# Erro "Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined"

Tags: prototypejs

Na loja aqui está dando um erro no prototype:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined
at klass.<anonymous> (product.js:128)
at prototype.js:391
at prototype.js:825
at klass._each (prototype.js:1237)
at klass.each (prototype.js:824)
at klass.updateImages (product.js:125)
at klass.initialize (product.js:55)
at klass (prototype.js:101)
at (index):1205
```

E no código com erro, aparece isso:

```js
var $break = {};
var Enumerable = (function() {
      function each(iterator, context) {
        var index = 0;
        try {
          this._each(function(value) {
            iterator.call(context, value, index++);
          });
        } catch (e) {
          if (e != $break) throw e;
        }
        return this;
      }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que é `iterator` e `context`?

Comment: Esse é o pior, é do Magento isso. Não fui eu que fiz do 0. No caso, acho que é do Prototype. Ja está na própria documentação: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3.0/prototype.js